# How can I get this code to apply the styling only where I want it?

Tags: html, css, styles

I am looking to style only 1 part of a page on my website. The end result is a box with rounded corners.

When I use the code in a basic 'test' text editor, it works beautifully.

However, when I put it on the page of my site, it styles the entire page instead of only the 1 part I want it to style.

I previously thought I found an answer with `<style scoped>` (with everything wrapped in `<div>` tags) only to learn there's no browser support. I was led to a plugin that may have corrected the browser support issue, only it would not load so I cannot use it.

If it helps, this is a Wordpress site. I also had to disable the wpautop in my functions.php. Before I did that, it was wrapping all of the styling in `<p>` tags that I didn't put there.

Another common result I've gotten is that the bottom "ul" pieces and the text of those 'ul' pieces will display, but without any of the styling.

I did also try to wrap the entire thing in `<div>` tags, but that didn't work either.

If you need additional information, please let me know.

Otherwise, thanks in advance for any ideas!

If it's useful, here's the code (back to `<style type="text/css">` instead of scoped):

```
<style type="text/css">
UL {
border-radius: 20px/20px;
-webkit-border-radius: 20px/20px;
-moz-border-radius: 20px/20px;
-ms-border-radius: 20px/20px;
-o-border-radius: 20px/20px;
 height: 150px;
 width: 500px;
    background: #7220c9;
    margin: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    -o-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
                                          /* No borders set */
  }
  LI {
    color: black;                /* text color is black */
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    background: white;           /* Content, padding will be white */
    border-radius: 20px/20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px/20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px/20px;
    -ms-border-radius: 20px/20px;
    -o-border-radius: 20px/20px;
    margin: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
    padding: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
    list-style: none             /* no glyphs before a list item */
                                          /* No borders set */
  }
  LI.withborder {
    border-radius: 20px/20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px/20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px/20px;
    -ms-border-radius: 20px/20px;
    -o-border-radius: 20px/20px;
    border-style: none;
    border-width: medium;        /* sets border width on all sides */
    border-color: #27d130;
  }
</STYLE>

<UL>
  <LI><b><center>Here is some text.</center></b>
  <LI class="withborder">This is some additional text.</a>.
</UL>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but you can use classes to style a specific part of your site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you've set the styling to include every UL and LI tag in the page. to make it specific to only some part, you should use either `class` names or set `id`s for them. something like:

```
.ul UL {
    /* style here */
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="ul">  <!-- only this particular UL will be affected -->
```

I see you've used that in your `<li>` tag with `withborder` class, you need to do the same with the `<ul>` tags also.

Comment: Thank-you so very, very much! This is what has worked! Thank-you so much everyone!

Comment: no problem :) that's what we do on SO, answer each other's questions. however, the method of thanking on SO is really voting the answer UP in addition to accepting as the correct answer ;)

Comment: Well, I'd be happy to, but the system tells me I can't vote up yet. I did mark it as the accepted answer though!

Answer (score 0):

```
be sure to end your lines
<li><b><center>Here is some text.</center></b></li>
```

Just as long as there are no other unordered lists you are fine. otherwise you will have to create a separate class that is your standard unformatted class for all other unordered lists. by

```
UL {
border-radius: 20px/20px;
-webkit-border-radius: 20px/20px;
-moz-border-radius: 20px/20px;
-ms-border-radius: 20px/20px;
-o-border-radius: 20px/20px;
height: 150px;
width: 500px;
background: #7220c9;
margin: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
-ms-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
-o-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
```

you are effectively styling every unordered list on your page. Be sure to create a form of delineation through classes for all of you unordered lists.

Comment: Thank-you for the very valuable explanation!